# html and body elts around polymer element

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

What is the reason to put custom element decls insde html, body and head tags?

Like the  my-list and my-greeting from https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit:

```
<html><head><link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-styles/typography.html">

    </head><body><dom-module id="my-list">
      <template>
        ....
      </template>

      </dom-module>
    <script src="my-list.js"></script>
```

The following, without html, body and head

```
    <dom-module id="my-list">
      <template>
        ....
      </template>
      <script>
         .....
      </script>
      </dom-module>
```

works quite ok. Is there some spec or anything which requires html & body around custom element?

Comment: FYI: `</head>` just closes the head of the HTML document. The elements are essentially inside the `<body>`.

Comment: @user656449 Can you please also edit the code, otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: ups, sorry, put wrong tags in the question. But it's a component, not a 'normal' page, is it? And it works quite ok just with 'dom-module' as top-level tag.  So why html and body?

Comment: ok, from the third attempt the question finally looks as it should

Comment: I still am quite unsure what the question actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create HTML files which are just elements. Such files don't do anything useful when loaded into the browser. Such element-only files don't need `<html><head><body>`, just `<dom-module>`, but they need to be imported in an entry page (usually named `index.html`) which actually does have `<html><head><body>` tags.

You can also define elements inline in an entry page directly (in the `<body>` tag), instead of importing them from another file.

Comment: That's exactly how I took  it too -  and never used to put <html><head><body> around custom elts.  But 'polymer-starter-kit', which is kind of a reference app, wraps custom elts inside html and body and it makes me at least a bit warried - should I  wrap my elts too? Will there be some side-effect if I don't? But there're quite a lot of elts in my apps already, so I want to know if there is some strong reason to do so...